# prismjs (code highlight plug-in) shows code horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, code-hinting

[prismjs.com](http://prismjs.com/)
is a way to display source code on your web site by highlighting it, similar to the monokai style...

The problem is that the plugin shows my codes horizontally. I would like my code to be structured (easy to read, on multiple lines) rather than being concatenated on several lines.

See here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNZdV.png)

[image: what i home like result]

Note: I'm using bootstrap on my web site.

Comment: Does this help in anyway? http://jsbeautifier.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, I didn't include [Keep Markup](http://prismjs.com/plugins/keep-markup/) plugin for prismjs. my bad